# How to find mortgage lender that will accept cost approach appraisal?

Tags: mortgage-qualification

I was applying for a refinance loan with my local credit union, and all was going well, when the appraiser (who had appraised the house previously) brought up the fact that it would most likely end up being a cost appraisal instead of a comparison appraisal (house is uniquely large), which the credit union doesn't accept.

Now that I am not using my local credit union, I don't have a particular source for the loan in mind, but I don't really want to go through a bunch of hoops just to find out that they will insist upon a comparison appraisal as well.  How can I find lenders that will accept a sot appraisal?

If it matters the current mortgage is IMO at least 1/3 of any possible appraised value, and I'll be at least doubling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would contact a mortgage broker. They work with multiple lenders. They may have one or more they work with that will accept non-standard appraisals.

In some parts of every region there are houses that aren't inside massive developments with dozens or hundreds of similar homes to compare with. There have to be lenders that finance those purchases. The mortgage broker may also know of good appraisers that are experts in those non-standard appraisals.